New Zealand chapter book about a runaway girl from a foster home who can talk to animals
I read this in 90's/2000's.
The girl's parents had sold marijuana, and she was sent to a foster home run by a mean woman. She escaped down a tree and met a cat named Homer, and they went to find her parents.

Can she also grunt and squeak and squawk with the animals?

You've given quite a lot more info in your question on Reddit; https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/1bzd0mz/new_zealand_chapter_book_about_runaway_girl_who/

Elements of this sound like Greenwild
